# In-App FTP Access, How to keep my password safe?

Tags: objective-c, macos, ftp, password-protection

I am planning pin making an ftp client, however how in my code in objective-c for my mac application can I keep my username and password safe? They will be in the code, so how can they be kept safe?

Whats an alternative solution? My app will automatically without the user having to enter any credentials allow them to download form my ftp server.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Allow anonymous downloads so you don't need to provide a username and password?

Comment: I'd agree - allowing anonymous does seem like a good idea, unless there's a good reason not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Keychain to keep such things safe.  You can read about it here...

[About keychain stuff](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html)

You'll also find a fair few keychain topics on this site.